# Deserialize a single XML tag into separate properties with C#

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

Consider the following simplified XML. I get it passed from a service and don't have any influence on its structure. It contains 3 tags that are defined by their order, i.e. the first-occuring `<string>` always refers to the same *property*.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <entry>
      <string>foo</string>
      <int>42</int>
      <string>bar</string>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <string>baz</string>
      <int>1234</int>
      <string>foobar</string>
   </entry>
</result>
```

I'd like to deserialize the `<entry>` elements into a class with separate properties, e.g.

```cs
public class ResultEntry {
  // this property equals to the 1st-occuring <string> element in the XML
  public String PropA { get; set; }
  // this property equals to the 2nd-occuring <string> element in the XML
  public String PropB { get; set; }
  // this property equals to the <int> element in the XML
  public Int32  PropC { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to deserialize the two `<string>` elements into the two different properties? I can't just add the `[XmlElement(ElementName="string")]` annotation to both of them, as this results an an `InvalidOperationException`.

One way could be to add a property like

```cs
[XmlElement(ElementName="string")]
public List<string> StringVals {get; set;}
```

instead, and to manually *move* the values later on, but this feels way too *hacky* to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication161
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
            Result result = (Result)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("result")]
    public class Result
    {
        [XmlElement("entry")]
        public List<ResultEntry> entries { get; set; }
    }
    public class ResultEntry
    {
        [XmlElement("string")]
        public List<String> PropA { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("int")]
        public int PropB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

You could do something like below which I do not recommend

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication161
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
            Result result = (Result)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("result")]
    public class Result
    {
        [XmlElement("entry")]
        public List<ResultEntry> entries { get; set; }
    }
    public class ResultEntry
    {
        private string PropA { get; set; }
        private string PropB { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("string")]
        public List<String> Properties {
            get { return new List<string> { PropA, PropB};}
            set { PropA = value[0]; PropB = value[1]; }
        }
        [XmlElement("int")]
        public int PropC { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my question was about **not** using a `List<String>`, but two String properties `PropA` and `PropB`, so the two `<string>` tags are deserialized into those two properties

Comment: Serialization is base on the tag names in the xml and not the property names in c#.  Both tags are <string>.  The only way of distinguishing the two tags are by the order they appear in the xml.